# How to optimize sata hard disk in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, optimization

How to optimize sata hard disk - HDD (Not A SSD) in ubuntu 12.04 for better performance.

- Hard Disk ( HDD ): 500 GB - Not a SSD
- Ram: 4GB 1GB
- 1 GB Nvidia Graphic Card
- Intel Core i5 Second Generation Procesor

Answer (score 2):

If your computer use involves accessing lots of files, I would suggest you mount your HDD with "noatime" option. You will see significant improvement because not every file-read will be written to filesystem.

So, in your `/etc/fstab` add this:

`UUID=24d75db7-ceca-40f7-ac21-979870a15ad6 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1`

Hope this helps any.

Answer (score 1):

`hdparm` is a command line utility for the Linux operating systems to set and view SATA and IDE hard disk hardware parameters. It can set parameters such as drive caches, sleep mode, power management, acoustic management, and DMA settings.

Changing hardware parameters from suboptimal conservative defaults to their optimal settings can improve performance greatly. For example, turning on DMA can in some instances double or triple data throughput.

Usage:

```bsh
sudo su                   # Login as root

hdparm -tT /dev/sda       # Perform device read timings and cache read timings

hdparm /dev/sda           # To check the current settings of /dev/sda

hdparm -i /dev/sda        # Display drive identification.
```

Read more from [here](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.in/2009/09/speeding-up-linux-using-hdparm-optimize.html).